# Why are these lines of code legal in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pylint

**Edit:** It seems this question is confused with list slicing and wrong code being used. Clarified the question further.

I would like to ask what do the following 2 lines of code **literally** mean in python.

```
In [51]: data = list(range(10))                                                                              
In [53]: data[-1]
```

**Background**

I accidentally ran the above raw Jupyter Notebook output through a python syntax checker (pylint) and surprisingly it did not throw out a syntax error, but instead

```
In [53]: data[-1]  
   ^ (bad-whitespace)
code2.py:1:0: C0111: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
code2.py:1:0: E0602: Undefined variable 'In' (undefined-variable)
code2.py:1:9: E0602: Undefined variable 'data' (undefined-variable)
code2.py:2:0: E0602: Undefined variable 'In' (undefined-variable)
code2.py:2:9: E0602: Undefined variable 'data' (undefined-variable)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -115.00/10 (previous run: -90.00/10, -25.00)
```

So I tried understanding what those lines of code were literally doing.

And I tried plugging in the missing variables.

This Is where I got the following result that looks like a dictionary assignment.

```
In = {}
data = ['apple'] # This list needed values, otherwise data[-1] threw an error

In [51]: data = list(range(10))                                                                              
In [53]: data[-1] 

print(In)    # {51: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}

# Why were there no values for key 53? (either {53: 'apple'})
```

I could not really understand what is going on with the 2 lines of code.

I didn't think that this line of code was legal `In [51]: data = list(range(10))` and since it was so, why did `In [53]` value not get assigned after that?

So any explanation or direction to references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I guess my question got misunderstood. I was trying to clarify why the code was legal to python. Updated my question, hopefully I got my question across better this time :)

Comment: [Variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

Comment: @Goyo oh that's really helpful. Thanks I got to learn something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be answering this question in case anybody had the same questions as me.

Thanks to @Goyo for pointing me towards [Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#implementation) which was introduced in Python 3.6

```
variable: annotation = assignment
```

This syntax is used to annotate types in variables as compared to using comments (`fruit: str = 'apple'` vs `fruit = 'apple' # type: str`).

The value in the annotation field is not strictly enforced and that was the reason why the syntax was legal.

First statement

```
In [51]: data = list(range(10))

Variable = In [51] 
Annotation = data
Assignment = list(range(10))
```

Second statement

```
In [53]: data[-1]

Variable = In [53]
Annotation = data[-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You never assign a value to

```
In [53]
```

You just access this part of the dictionary. If you do something like this the entry appears in the dict.

```
In[53]: data[-1] = 'hello world'

Result: {51: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 53: 'hello world'}
```